# Not working Send() and Mouse Click in window with Class:SunAwtFrame on third level

Tags: autoit, oracle-fusion-middleware

I try to automate procedures in my Oracle MiddleWare Environment and when I get to the bottom of it, where I should click "Run" button (in Cyrrilic), I can't do this with Send, or Control, or Mouse. However, it is third level of the submenu, all other levels work (I know the usual problems with Frames, but it works for other levels, than why?))

The summary from Info is below:

> > > > Window <<<<
> > > >         Title:  My Window
> > > >         Class:  SunAwtFrame
> > > >         Position:   0, 0
> > > >         Size:   820, 660
> > > >         Style:  0x16CF0000
> > > >         ExStyle:    0x00000100
> > > >         Handle: 0x00171058
> > > >
> > > > Control <<<<
> > > >         Class:
> > > >         Instance:
> > > >         ClassnameNN:
> > > >         Name:
> > > >         Advanced (Class):
> > > >         ID: 
> > > >         Text:
> > > >         Position:
> > > >         Size:
> > > >         ControlClick Coords:
> > > >         Style:
> > > >         ExStyle:
> > > >         Handle: 0x000910F4
> > > >
> > > > Mouse <<<<
> > > >         Position:   448, 427
> > > >         Cursor ID:  0
> > > >         Color:  0xC0FFFF
> > > >
> > > > StatusBar <<<<
> > > >
> > > > ToolsBar <<<<
> > > >
> > > > Visible Text <<<<
> > > >
> > > > Hidden Text <<<<

```
Local $sLogin = InputBox("Security Check", "Enter your login", "")
Local $sPasswd = InputBox("Security Check", "Enter your password.", "","-")

$oIE = _IECreate("https://******************",0,0,1,1)
$oLinks = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input")
For $oLink In $oLinks
If String($oLink.type) = "button" And String($oLink.value) = "RUN" Then
      _IEAction($oLink, "click")
      ExitLoop
EndIf
Next
_IELoadWait($oIE, 1000)
Sleep(15000)
_WinWaitActivate("Oracle Fusion Middleware Forms Services","")
Send($sLogin)
Send("{TAB}")
Send($sPasswd)
Send("{TAB}")
Send("{SHIFTDOWN}prod{SHIFTUP}9{ENTER}")
_WinWaitActivate("My Window","")
Send("{TAB}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN} 
{DOWN}{UP}{RIGHT}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{RIGHT}{DOWN}{DOWN}{RIGHT}{DOWN} 
{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{RIGHT}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}")
        *//And here it stops working without any error.//       
Send("03/01/2019")
Send("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
MouseMove(268,363,25)
MouseClick("primary")
```

Please note that I cannot change anything at all in Oracle MiddleWare environment or on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this for your class `SunAwtFrame` the question is too unclear. But your code has some issues.

1. `_WinWaitActivate()` with `Sleep(15000)` isn't necessary because you can use `WinWaitActive($sTitle, $sText, $iTimeout)` with a timeout of 15 seconds as third parameter.
2. Your problem for the stopping should be the line 21. You can not add a new line within a function parameter without using of `& _` at the end of the line. Use a function like `_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes()` to avoid such long parameter values.
3. You also could shorten your `MouseMove()` and then `MouseClick()` action by doing `MouseClick('left', 268, 363)` to the target mouse position.

Here a reworked version of your code:

```
#include-once
#include <IE.au3>

Global $sLogin  = InputBox('Security Check', 'Enter your login', '')
Global $sPasswd = InputBox('Security Check', 'Enter your password.', '', '-')
Global $oIE     = _IECreate('https://******************', 0, 0, 1, 1)
Global $oLinks  = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, 'input')

Func _clickButtonRun()
    For $oLink In $oLinks
        If String($oLink.type) == 'button' And String($oLink.value) == 'RUN' Then
            _IEAction($oLink, 'click')
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
    Next
EndFunc

Func _sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes($sKey, $iHowOften = 1)
    For $i = 1 To $iHowOften Step 1
        Send($sKey)
        Sleep(200) ; to increase the robustness wait a bit between each input/send
    Next
EndFunc

_clickButtonRun()
_IELoadWait($oIE, 1000)
WinWaitActive('Oracle Fusion Middleware Forms Services', '', 15)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes($sLogin)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{TAB}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes($sPasswd)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{TAB}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('PROD9')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{ENTER}')
WinWaitActive('My Window', '', 5)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{TAB}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{DOWN}', 11)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{UP}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{RIGHT}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{DOWN}', 4)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{RIGHT}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{DOWN}', 2)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{RIGHT}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{DOWN}', 5)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{RIGHT}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{DOWN}', 4)
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{ENTER}')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('03/01/2019')
_sendKeystrokesSeveralTimes('{TAB}', 3)
MouseClick('left', 268, 363)
```

Comment: Hey @user10815634 can you please help me with my latest question